# Generic interfaces and inheritance to call a generic method

Tags: c#

I want to have a generic class which could call a method based on its generic type which is defined by a derived class. For that I implemented a base interface and a generic interface which has the base interface as generic and also derives from the base interface.

In the generic interface I want a method based on the type T of the base interface.

After that I wanted to implement a class based on the generic interface which should be able to call the generic method. This is the example code:

```
public interface BaseInterface
{ }

public interface GenericInterface<T> : BaseInterface where T : BaseInterface
{
    void Foo(T t);
}

public class C<T> : GenericInterface<T> where T : BaseInterface
{
    public C()
    {
        // None of these works
        Foo(this);
        Foo((T)this);
        Foo((BaseInterface)this);   
    }

    public void Foo(T t) { }
}
```

Is there a way to achieve my desired behavior here?

The error message here is:

```
cannot convert from 'C<T>' to 'T'
```

which in my eyes should be possible because C derives from BaseInterface which is T

Comment: pay attention: T != C<T> and 
C<T> = this, Foo signature is for T but this of instance  is =  C<T> and you can change the signature of Foo  to public void Foo(BaseInterface t) { }  and implements this

Comment: You open my mind bro..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what you need for the Curiously Recurring Template in C#.

```
public interface BaseInterface { }
public interface GenericInterface<T> : BaseInterface where T : GenericInterface<T>
{
    void Foo(T t);
}

public abstract class C<T> : GenericInterface<T> where T : C<T>
{
    public abstract void Foo(T t);
}
```

Now you can go ahead and implement a real class:

```
public class D : C<D>
{
    public D()
    {
        Foo(this);
        Foo((D)this);
    }

    public override void Foo(D t) { }
}
```

That works fine.

However, calling `Foo((BaseInterface)this);` will never work in this code. It just doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 3):

While both `C<T>` and `T` need to derive from BaseInterface, that does not mean that then need to be the *same*. I might for example declare another type `B : BaseInterface`, and `C<B>`. So we would get the method `Foo(B t)` , it would obviously not be possible to call the method with `this` as the parameter, since `C<B>` is not `B`.

If you just need a method that needs a `BaseInterface` parameter, just declare it as `Foo(BaseInterface t)` instead. That way you could call it with `this` without any problem.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're looking for something like the Curiously Recurring Template Pattern for C#. In a simplified form it looks like this:

```
class Base<T>
{
    public void Foo(T t) { }
}

class C : Base<C>
{
    C()
    {
        Foo(this);
    }
}
```

In your case `T` is a type that derives from `BaseInterface`. Although `C<T>` also derives from `BaseInterface` it doesn't mean that you can bind a `C<T>` to `T t`. It's like trying to bind a `string` to a `List`, just because both implement `IEnumerable`. They are still different types.

For your full example it could look like this

```
public interface BaseInterface
{ }

public interface GenericInterface<T> : BaseInterface where T : BaseInterface
{
    void Foo(T t);
}

public class C<T> : GenericInterface<C<T>> where T : BaseInterface
{
    public C()
    {
        Foo(this);
    }

    public void Foo(C<T> t) { }
}
```

Comment: That's not a correct CRT implementation.

Comment: @Enigmativity As "something like CRTP [..] in a simplified form" I'd say it's a valid implementation or exactly what is shown here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern#General_form . But you could give us a glimpse of what a real CRT would look like. :)

Answer (score 1):

I Tried this, maybe can help you

```
public class C<T> : GenericInterface<T> where T : BaseInterface
{
    public C()
    {
        T t = default(T);
        BaseInterface bi;
        bi = t; // here can cast , bacuse T : BaseInterface , not BaseInterface : T
        t = bi;//here cast error , 
    }

    public void Foo(T t) { }
}
```

It's same like this case:

```
public class B { }
public class A : B
{
    public void CastTest()
    {
        A a = null;
        B b = null;
        b = a;
        a = b;//here error
    }
}
```